# Video Editing: Camera view

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to know if it is possible to see that what camera see in the layout in video editor, but not a full rendered movie just a render preview. I need it because I need to switch to change the animation while I manage subtitles.

edit:

The method of Crantisz work but the preview is a little different that the preview that I have in the layout. It miss something in the animation. In my animation the spheres follow the polyhedrons and in the video edditing preview it don't.

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the separate scene. If your animation in the default Scene, add a new one.

In the new scene, you will be able to select your first scene:

[image]

Preview by default is solid, but you can change if you want:

[image]

Comment: I answered you lower.

Comment: This is not the answer, edit your question instead

Answer (score 0):

To get instant updates of the 3D View in the VSE, you'll need to do a Linked Copy of the scene and add this scene as Scene Strip to the Sequencer. As described here, you'll need to switch off the cache and update with Crtl+R and/or move the play head to see the updates: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/suggestion-make-the-sequencer-contents-into-data-block-which-can-override-the-switched-to-scene-sequencer-contents/16562/9

Alternatively, you can use the alternative version of Scene Strip Tools, which will set up the Linked Copy scene automatic for you when adding a camera: https://github.com/tin2tin/scene_strip_tools/tree/linked_copy

[image]

Comment: Hello. Idon't understand clearly how to download and install the scene strip tool in your link. When I click on "Download and install this file: https://github.com/tin2tin/scene_strip_tools/raw/master/scene_strip_tools.py" it show me a huge page whith scripts.

Comment: At the begening of the script it says "# Run the script:
# 1. Run the script in the text-editor." But what is the text editor?

Comment: I found how to install it. Now I selected the scene strip then click on "link sequencer to 3D viewport" but nothing change.

Comment: You'll need to select a camera in the 3d view and click on the Add Camera button, Then repeat until you have several strips in the sequencer. With link sequencer to 3d viewport checked the cameras should now be switching in the 3d view according to the strip lengths in the VSE.

Comment: Why "several strips" while I just need one? I did what you say but still no change.

Comment: You won't see any camera switching if you only have one camera.

Comment: Still I don't see change with various little camera strips.

Comment: And I I don't follow the Crantisz method there is nothing on the screen.